# Post image to user wall via FB Api

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-wall

Hi i am trying to post image to friends wall from my FB app. I have this code, but dont know how to attach image to the post. It only posts text. Anybody has working example ? Or where i have error ? thanks.

FULL PATH TO IMAGE HERE - replaced with path to image
FULL PATH TO MY FB APP HERE - replace with path to fb app.

```
FB.ui(
   {
     target_id: '100000505490012',
     method: 'stream.publish',
     message: 'Just Testing!!!.',
     attachment: {
       name: 'test name',
       caption: 'Caption here.',
       description: (
         'description here'
       ),
       href: 'http://facebook.com/mysite'
     },
      media: {
            type: 'image',
            src: 'FULL PATH TO IMAGE HERE',
             href:'FULL PATH TO MY FB APP HERE'
             },
     action_links: [
       { text: 'Code', href: 'FULL PATH TO MY FB APP HERE' }
     ],
     user_prompt_message: 'Personal message here'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The media attribute actually goes inside the attachment attribute.

```
FB.ui({
  target_id: '100000505490012',
  method: 'stream.publish',
  message: 'Just Testing!!!.',
  attachment: {
    name: 'test name',
    caption: 'Caption here.',
    description: 'description here',
    href: 'http://facebook.com/mysite',
    media: [{ 'type': 'image', 'src': 'FULL PATH TO IMAGE HERE', 'href':'FULL PATH TO MY FB APP HERE'}]
  },
  action_links: [{ text: 'Code', href: 'FULL PATH TO MY FB APP HERE' }],
  user_prompt_message: 'Personal message here'
},
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```